# How do i revert adding a permenant boot arg from initramfs?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, initramfs

i was trying to fix a crash issue by adding a boot paramtr ([How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)) <- this
and now am stuck in initramfs everytime i boot (i did the permenant boot paramtr).

please let me know if i can revert it somehow using initramfs.

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; but just use <E> to edit the entry when you boot the OS at `grub`.  If grub isn't showing; you can use a key to make it show; but you've provided no OS & release details - so use the appropriate key for your *unstated* release (shift, esc etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot into recovery mode from the Grub menu and this will bypass the kernel arguments on `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. From recovery mode, you will be able to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file to remove the arguments. Also, don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes after you are finished editing the file.

To explain: arguments listed after `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` are not passed on when using recovery mode. [See here for more information.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440962)